# SQL query to calculate the sum of values in column, where column name has comma in it

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to calculate the sum of values in a column using SQL query, wherein the column name has comma in it?
Below is a sample table:

```
Saint Petersburg, Russia
7.34
29.35
4.4
```

Output required== SUM(7.34+29.35+4.4)
Thanks

Comment: Ugh. Why do you have a column with that name in the first place? That has less than ideal normalization choices written all over it.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select sum([Saint Petersburg, Russia])
from t;
```

You need to escape the column name and the traditional escape method in SQL Server uses square braces.  Double quotes can also be used.

If the issue is that `'Saint Petersburg, Russia'` is a potential *value* in a character column you want to sum, then use `try_convert()`:

```
select sum(try_convert(numeric(20, 4), col)
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! this worked. I wasnot using the brackets for column name.